# terminating blocking goroutines with errgroup

Tags: go, goroutine

I have two tasks that are running in go routines. I am using errgroup. I am not sure how to use the errgroup.WithContext correctly.

In the following code, task1 is returning the error and I would like to terminate task2 (long running) when that happens. Please note that in this example time.sleep is added just to simulate my problem. In reality task1 and task2 are doing real work and does not have any sleep call.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/sync/errgroup"
    "time"
)

func task1(ctx context.Context) error {
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("first finished, pretend error happened")
    return ctx.Err()
}

func task2(ctx context.Context) error {
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        fmt.Println("task 1 is finished with error")
        return ctx.Err()
    default:
        fmt.Println("second started")
        time.Sleep(50 * time.Second)
        fmt.Println("second finished")
    }
    return nil
}

func test() (err error) {
    ctx := context.Background()
    g, gctx := errgroup.WithContext(ctx)

    g.Go(func() error {
        return task1(gctx)
    })

    g.Go(func() error {
        return task2(gctx)
    })

    err = g.Wait()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("wait done")
    }

    return err
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("main")
    err := test()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("main err")
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
}
```

Comment: `return ctx.Err()` this does not return an error if context has not timed out.

Comment: I wrote [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73848427/11810946) that may help earlier today. In your case `task2` only checks the `context` when first started, cancelling the `context` whilst `time.Sleep` is running will have no impact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's up to your tasks to handle [context](https://pkg.go.dev/context) cancellation properly and not `time.Sleep` inside a select.

As stated in errgroup documentation:

> WithContext returns a new Group and an associated Context derived from ctx.
>
> The derived Context is canceled the first time a function passed to Go returns a non-nil error or the first time Wait returns, whichever occurs first.

You are using error group right, but your context handling needs a refactor.

Here is a refacor of your task 2:

```
func task2(ctx context.Context) error {
    errCh := make(chan bool)

    go func() {
        time.Sleep(50 * time.Second)
        errCh <- true
    }()

    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        return fmt.Errorf("context done: %w", ctx.Err())
    case <-errCh:
        return errors.New("task 2 failed")
    }
}
```

With such select, you wait for the first channel to emit. In this case, it is the context expiration, unless you modify time sleep to be lower. Example [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/tZRPdbiA1Lf).

Comment: The `for` and `select` in your code are redundant (you always `return` so never loop and `select` only has one `case` so can be replaced with `<-ctx.Done()`). That makes the answer confusing because it's not clear how work would be done.

Comment: you right, I wanted to prepare a boilerplate code. Here is with a time out in the handling.

Comment: Better but the `for` is still redundant (both legs of the `select` `return`).